# Fix changing owner to Root of multiple system files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions

I accidentally ran this command

```
# chown -R root:root /{usr,lib,var,etc,bin,sbin,tools}
```

on my ubuntu 23.04 system.

How can I fix permissions?
Can this be done without reinstalling?

Thanks

Comment: Restore your backups. If you don't have them, reinstall.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll start preparing the installation medium